# How can I merge these two arrays to create this JSON format, React

Tags: json, reactjs

How can I take two arrays such as these:

```
const age = [31,53,62]
const names = ['john', 'sam', 'kathy']
```

And format them into the following:

```
const data = {
  "children": [
    { "id": 1,
      "name": "john",
      "age": 31,
    },
    { "id": 2,
      "name": "sam",
      "age": 53,
    },
    { "id": 3,
      "name": "kathy",
      "age": 62,
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#map` to generate your array of object. You can map names with age using the index.

```js
const age = [31,53,62],
      names = ['john', 'sam', 'kathy'],
      result = {children: age.map((a,i) => ({id: i+1, name: names[i], age: a}))};
console.log(result);
```